# How to send a message without replying to a slash-command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having trouble finding a way to hide the command message above a bot's "interaction.reply()" message. I just want the message to be public (not ephemeral), without it being a reply to a command or getting an error message. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by command message? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Have you tried `interaction.channel.send()`

Comment: @Elitezen Yes that kinda works, but I get an error message saying: "This interaction failed".

Comment: The interaction must be replied to, else that will happen

Comment: Then is there anyway to hide it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem has been resolved with this:

```
interaction.deferReply();
interaction.deleteReply();
interaction.channel.send("dummy message");
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand what you meant by that
but this might be what you were looking for

You need to reply then delete it

```
interaction.reply({ content: 'dummy message', fetchReply: true })
  .then((message) => message.delete())
  .catch(console.error);
```